# Android Studio Lock Screen Buttons and Text

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, lockscreen

I'm building a media player app and I want to have buttons to play/pause, and go to the next and previous song in the lock screen while the app is running. I've been searching for how to do this for a while and I can't seem to get a simple answer or instructions on what to do. The way to do this seems to have changed a number of times and I just can't find a working solution. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you ever work with remote view in Android?

Comment: Can you provide code? The documentation doesn't really seem to help..